# Weird thing occurs when using sizetofit of a UITextView in IOS7

Tags: uitextview, ios7, sizetofit

When I test my app on IOS7 simulator.
Sometimes I found it is weird when I using `sizeToFit` of a `UITextView`.
The frame after `sizeToFit` seems right but the text can only show partly just like the photo below. (The gray area represents the `UITextView` new frame after `sizeToFit`, the whole sentence should be "which sparked a tense relationship between the two.")

[image]

The `UITextView` text is set via attributedText.
It seems the problem occurs with some sentences only and is OK for most sentences.

I met this problem several times and can not solve it yet.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

Finally I solve the problem in an ugly way. I reset the text of the textView.

```
NSString *text = textView.text;
textView.text = @"";
textView.text = text;
```

Now it can show the whole content after sizeToFit.
I think it seems like a IOS 7's bug.

Comment: Increase the Textview frame height.

Comment: I already set the backGroundColor of the UITextView to gray color. (the gray area of the photo above).
The Textview frame height is enough to show the whole text.

Comment: Maybe [textView setNeedDisplay] ?

Comment: To Kyle Fang, Thanks for reply. I tried setNeedDisplay and it did not work.

Comment: To CupraR_On_Rails: 
Finally I solve the problem in an ugly way. I reset the text of the textView.

NSString *text = textView.text;
textView.text = @"";
textView.text = text;

I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, it took me a while to figure it out, you simply need to resize the **text container**

```
[textview sizeToFit];
[textview.textContainer setSize:textview.frame.size];
```

Comment: Great find, saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

Noticed in IOS7 sizeToFit wasn't working also - perhaps the solution may help you too, needs the additional layoutIfNeeded

```
[UITEXTVIEW sizeToFit];
[UITEXTVIEW layoutIfNeeded];
[UITEXTVIEW setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: This was the difference of going onto new lines and not - SAVED! - thank you and thanks Apple for default padding/margins that took days to work out :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got "clip subviews" checked in interface builder?

Try to uncheck it or setting this property to "NO".

Comment: I create UITextView by coding and not used interface builder.
I can not find the clipSubviews property also.
Can you give me some hints?

Comment: this can be done in code by setting `clipsToBounds = NO`, but this doesn't appear to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me.

```
[textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```