# What is the most concise and semantic way to lay out a paragraph of text of variable length for IOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

As far as I know, laying out paragraphs can be done with:

a) UITextView

- Resizing the textview to fit the content in didlayoutsubviews

  - Example here: [Weird thing occurs when using sizetofit of a UITextView in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928832/weird-thing-occurs-when-using-sizetofit-of-a-uitextview-in-ios7)

b) UILabel

- Setting the Lines to 0, using sizetofit

  - Example here: [Multiple lines of text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel)

However, I am unable to get either of these to work in IOS7 (having previously used them in ios6.x). There *must* be a definitive and clear way to just *lay out a paragraph*, its such a seemingly simple task.To be specific, this is just a paragraph of text that is:

- non-editable
- variable length
- Works consistently whether using storyboards or code only

So please, what is *the* way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` works fine on iOS 7. If you don't use Auto Layout, then calling `sizeToFit` on `UITextView` object should be enough. If you do use Auto Layout, then make a height constraint on `UITextView` object and set its `constant` in code in the following way:

```
CGSize sizeThatFits = [self.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(yourAvailableWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = ceilf(sizeThatFits.height);
```

I've seen some problems with `UILabel` recently, e.g. [Lines missing from tall UILabel when embedding NSTextAttachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253224/lines-missing-from-tall-uilabel-when-embedding-nstextattachment/19333196#19333196)

Answer (score 0):

With the UILabel, I was able to to get this working by:

- setting the lines to 0
- setting my line break mode to word wrap
- ensuring that the height constraint is set to a "greater than or equal to"